# Caculate current values based on pct_change and previous values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a dataframe as follows:

```
   type    price       pct      date
0     a  10918.0       NaN  2019/6/1
1     a      NaN  0.023631  2019/9/1
2     b  10379.0       NaN  2019/6/1
3     b      NaN  0.010984  2019/9/1
4     c   9466.0       NaN  2019/6/1
5     c      NaN  0.177160  2019/9/1
6     d  13637.0       NaN  2019/6/1
7     d      NaN  0.124661  2019/9/1
8     e  11774.0       NaN  2019/6/1
9     e      NaN -0.033124  2019/9/1
10    f      NaN  0.023124  2019/9/2
```

I hope to firstly filter rows which are not duplicated with:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['type'], keep=False)]
```

then calculate `price` in the date of `2019/9/1` based on `pct` and values from `2019/6/1`.

The final result will look like this:

```
  type  price       pct      date
0    a  10918       NaN  2019/6/1
1    a  11176  0.023631  2019/9/1
2    b  10379       NaN  2019/6/1
3    b  10493  0.010984  2019/9/1
4    c   9466       NaN  2019/6/1
5    c  11143  0.177160  2019/9/1
6    d  13637       NaN  2019/6/1
7    d  15337  0.124661  2019/9/1
8    e  11774       NaN  2019/6/1
9    e  11384 -0.033124  2019/9/1
```

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need guarenteed `price in the date of 2019/9/1 based on pct and values from 2019/6/1` you can working with `MultiIndex` - for select columns are used tuples:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['type'], keep=False)]
df = df.pivot_table(index='type', columns='date')
df[('price', '2019/9/1')] = (df[('pct', '2019/9/1')]*df[('price', '2019/6/1')] + 
                             df[('price', '2019/6/1')])
df = df.stack().reset_index()
print (df)
  type      date       pct         price
0    a  2019/6/1       NaN  10918.000000
1    a  2019/9/1  0.023631  11176.003258
2    b  2019/6/1       NaN  10379.000000
3    b  2019/9/1  0.010984  10493.002936
4    c  2019/6/1       NaN   9466.000000
5    c  2019/9/1  0.177160  11142.996560
6    d  2019/6/1       NaN  13637.000000
7    d  2019/9/1  0.124661  15337.002057
8    e  2019/6/1       NaN  11774.000000
9    e  2019/9/1 -0.033124  11383.998024
```

If always only 2 datetimes per each group:

```
#removed duplicates
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['type'], keep=False)]
#sorting for guarateed ordering
df = df.sort_values(['type','date'])

df['price'] = df['price'].ffill().mul(df['pct']).add(df['price'].ffill(), fill_value=0)
print (df)
  type         price       pct      date
0    a  10918.000000       NaN  2019/6/1
1    a  11176.003258  0.023631  2019/9/1
2    b  10379.000000       NaN  2019/6/1
3    b  10493.002936  0.010984  2019/9/1
4    c   9466.000000       NaN  2019/6/1
5    c  11142.996560  0.177160  2019/9/1
6    d  13637.000000       NaN  2019/6/1
7    d  15337.002057  0.124661  2019/9/1
8    e  11774.000000       NaN  2019/6/1
9    e  11383.998024 -0.033124  2019/9/1
```

Comment: Got a `KeyError: ('pct', '2019-09-01')`. ;(

Comment: @ahbon - added new solution.

Comment: After replace `price` for `date` in `2019-09-01`, your second method can help get correct calculations, thanks again.

Comment: For the first solution, I still get `KeyError: ('pct', '2019-09-01')`.

Comment: @ahbon - I think there are datetimes, so working change `'2019-09-01'` to `pd.Timestamp('2019-09-01')`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['type'], keep=False)]
df2 = df.copy()
df2['price'] = df2['price'].ffill()
df2['pct'] = df2['pct'].fillna(1)
df['price'][1::2] = df2['price'][1::2] + (df2['price']*df2['pct'])[1::2].round()
```

Output:

```
  type    price       pct      date
0    a  10918.0       NaN  2019/6/1
1    a  11176.0  0.023631  2019/9/1
2    b  10379.0       NaN  2019/6/1
3    b  10493.0  0.010984  2019/9/1
4    c   9466.0       NaN  2019/6/1
5    c  11143.0  0.177160  2019/9/1
6    d  13637.0       NaN  2019/6/1
7    d  15337.0  0.124661  2019/9/1
8    e  11774.0       NaN  2019/6/1
9    e  11384.0 -0.033124  2019/9/1
```

Comment: Thank you both, may I ask, what `df['price'][1::2]` stands for?

Comment: @ahbon every other value, so the second fourth sixth eight tenth and so on...

Comment: @ahbon So: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10][1::2]` will output: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

Comment: hmmm, so how is guarenteed `price in the date of 2019/9/1 based on pct and values from 2019/6/1` ?

Comment: @jezrael You're asking me??

Comment: sure, exactly, because comment under your question

Comment: Sorry for the late, I just tried this method, the code works smoothly, but `value`s calculated seems not correct.

Comment: Not yet, values calculated are not correct, I find rows in each type not always two.

Comment: @ahbon What you mean by not two?

Comment: @ahbon I just edited my answer few minutes ago, please copy and paste the code into your interpreter and try...

Comment: Two means in each type, only two rows of data for `2019-06-01` and `2019-09-01`.

Comment: I didn't get correct calculation with your new method, maybe the problem from `price` in the month of `2019-09-01` are not `NaN` for original data, I try with `df.loc[df.date == '2019-09-01', 'price'] = ''`, but it seems didn't replace the value. In fact, I need to update the `price` for `2019-09-01` with your method of calculation.